# Pass PDF fill form data from React app to node-pdftk (Express) via POST

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, pdf, post

Rather than declare the fill PDF formdata in Express, I'd like to pass formdata from my React app to node-pdftk.  The PDF displays correctly in the browser with the form data filled in when I link to the /pdf route in React:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/pdf">Form-fill PDF File</a>
```

Express app:

```
const pdftk = require('node-pdftk');

// Rather than declare form data here in Express,
const formdata = {
  'Fill_this_1': 'With this from Express 1',
  'Fill this 2': 'With this from Express 2',
  'Fill this 3': 'With this from Express 3'
}

app.get('/pdf', (req, res, next) => {
  pdftk
      .input('./file.pdf')
      .fillForm(formdata)
      .flatten()
      .output()
      .then(buf => {
          res.type('application/pdf');
          res.send(buf);
      })
      .catch(next);
});
```

I'd like to pass formdata from React via GET or POST:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const showFile = (blob) => {
  var newBlob = new Blob([blob], {type: "application/pdf"})
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
    return;
  } 
  const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = data;
  link.download="file.pdf";
  link.click();
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
  }, 100);
}

function FillPDFForm() {
    useEffect(() => {
      fillForm();
    }, [])

    // Trying to pass formdata to node-pdftk (Express) via POST
    const fillForm = async () => {
      await fetch('http://localhost:8080/pdf', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        'Fill_this_1': 'With this from React 1',
        'Fill_this_2': 'With this from React 2',
        'Fill_this_3': 'With this from React 3'
      })
    }).then(res => res.blob())
      .then(showFile)
   }
return (null);
}
export default FillPDFForm;
```

The PDF that downloads doesn't have any form fields filled out.  Does anyone have experience with passing PDF fill formdata from React to Express?

Answer (score 0):

All that was needed was to change `'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'` to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` inside `fillForm`.  Trying to send the body of the POST as application/pdf to Express isn't going to work.